Why is Google blocking a user login with "Failed login" when they entered the correct password?
Why does Google block me from logging into my own account when I enter the username and password correctly on the very first attempt?
Login Fail
I tried to login to a Google account that I haven't logged into in a while:

I went to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail
I entered the username and clicked Next
I entered the correct password and clicked Next
Google asks me for a phone number. There's none linked to the account (better security), and I clicked Try another way
Google gives me two options: [1] Get a verification code sent to your phone (not going to happen) and [2] Get help
I click Get help
I see a message that says:


Contact your domain admin for help. Learn more

That's not especially helpful, because I am the domain admin.
The article that it links to is a short stub of useless information

Sign in to your work, school, or other group account
You can't reset or recover the password to a work, school, or other group account on this page because your organization has restricted password changes. You'll need to contact your administrator.
For students who use Classroom, go to Troubleshooting for students.

I'm not interested in resting my password. I just want to login. Why is google not just opening my account after I enter the correct password on the first attempt?
Admin Console
Meanwhile, I put my admin hat on by logging-in in another browser:

I go to https://admin.google.com/
I enter the admin username and clicked Next
I enter the admin's correct password and clicked Next
I navigate to Directory -> Users
I find the user in the list and click on them
I click on the Security tab and confirm that Require password change is OFF
I click on the Investigate tab
I open Suspicious sign-ins and see 0 log entries
I open Failed sign-ins and see several failed logins -- all of them from me

Here's an example of the log of the failed login:

Date REDACTED
User REDACTED
Event Failed login
Description REDACTED failed to login
Login type Google password
Challenge type Password
Is suspicious False
Is second factor False
IP address REDACTED
Affected user
Email forwarding address
Sensitive action name
Login time
Domain REDACTED

The documentation for this Failed login event type is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login#login_failure

The reason for the login failure is supposed to be in a field titled login_failure_type, with the following possibilities:

login_failure_access_code_disallowed - The user does not have permission to login to the service.
login_failure_account_disabled - The user's account is disabled.
login_failure_invalid_password - The user's password was invalid.
login_failure_unknown - The reason for the login failure is not known.

Notice, of course, that this field is not login_failure_invalid_password -- so I definitely have the correct login credentials. Also notice that this field is actually completely missing from all these failed login log entries. So if google doesn't have a reason to prevent me from logging in, why the heck are they preventing me from logging-in??
Why did this login fail? And how can I, as the Admin of this gapps/gsuite account, tell Google to stop blocking users from logging-in when they enter their account credentials correctly?
Update
Despite the fact that the login entry above clearly says that Is suspicious = False, my gapps/gsuite admin account received an email from Google shortly after Google prevented me from being able to login:

Notification from Google
This Suspicious login alert is to inform you that Google has detected a suspicious login in your domain. Google considers login activity suspicious if we notice a sign in attempt that doesn't match a user's normal behavior, such as a sign in from an unusual location, or because we think an unauthorized person attempted to access a user's account.
The alert details include:
User: REDACTED
Attempted Login IP: REDACTED
Activity Date: REDACTED
Please view the alert center for additional details, investigation options, and remediation recommendations.

Note: If I go to the alert center, then I see zero entries about this login attempt -- which is consistent with the log entry above, but inconsistent with this email. wtf?
OK Google: it's not at all suspicious if a user enters a randomly-generated, 100-character password correctly on the very first login attempt after several months of no login attempts.
How do I tell Google to stop its false-positive blocking of our users from being able to login to their own accounts, especially when they entered the correct password on the first attempt?

See also https://old.reddit.com/r/gsuite/comments/14psu8s/how_do_i_disable_login_challenges_permanently/

See also How to disable login challenge security method permanently? on the Google Workplace Knowledge Center

@Blindspots Yes, this is 100% false-positive caused by Google's faulty anomaly detection, which happens to us almost every time we try to login to an old account that we haven't touched in a while. And there's zero actual failed logins from other people, which means that this "feature" is causing more harm than good. It's actually a security risk, since it functions as a DOS against our users.

@Blindspots As mentioned above, for security reasons we do not link phone numbers to accounts. That would introduce vulnerabilities. If possible, we'd prefer to configure Google Workspace to prevent the possibility for a user to use insecure SMS for anything related to authentication.

@Blindspots Google dumps the user at the message Contact your domain admin for help. Learn more. There is no way to continue at that point. I recommend re-reading the OP. All the information that you're asking is already there. But I'm happy to clarify if you're confused.

@Blindspots Information Security includes CIA. Availability is part of the triad. This questions is very much about security, as Google is effectively issuing a security attack on users in our organization, and I'm trying to figure out how to mitigate this risk.

@Blindspots would you mind updating your answer with this info? You don't, for example, mention hardware security keys or TOTP.

Answer has been updated to include available 2SV options.

Documentation Loops
It is not unusual for users to get caught in documentation loops as large companies like Google and Microsoft are better at adding and removing features to their gazillion apps and variations than they are at creating and maintaining accurate detailed documentation.
This may apply to all developers (r/ProgrammerHumor/documentation)
Your Problem

"I tried to login [sic] to a Google account that I haven't logged into in a while"

You are seeing a login challenge because Google flagged one, or more, of the following as unusual: login device, network, or location.
It's uncommon for companies like Google to share much about their abuse prevention systems or provide simple workarounds, such as allowing users to permanently secure accounts by username & password alone. For Google, the risks posed by security compromises go far beyond the immediate impact felt by owners of compromised accounts.
Login Challenges

"Google gives me two options: [1] Get a verification code sent to your phone (not going to happen) and [2] Get help"

 Google login challenges can't be permanently disabled.

Google Workspace (GWS) users can enable 2‐Step Verification* to manage login challenges or, if not enabled, allow Google to send a verification code to their phone when prompted.
* See 2-Step Verification (2SV) section below.
Outside of that, the remaining option is to "Get Help" from a GWS admin, and the "help" available to provide consists of:

Communicate with the user, provide information, and try to answer any questions (similar to this post)
Temporarily disable login challenges on their account for 10 minutes.

Go to Directory > Users from the main menu.
Click on a user then the Security tab on their information page.
Click on Login Challenge and then TURN OFF FOR 10 MINUTES







2-Step Verification (2SV)
GWS admins choose the 2SV options available for their users and whether it is required. Depending on the specific GWS subscription, 2SV is already mandatory for admin accounts, or else will be in the immediate future.
2SV options from most secure to least:

Security Key:* Hardware Key, or Device Passkey (Android/IOS/Computer)
* See Passwordless Single-Step Sign-In section below.
Google Prompt: Android/IOS
Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP): Various hardware and software-based code generators (eg. Google Authenticator).
Backup Codes: Generated in account ahead of time. Are vulnerable if not stored safely.
SMS or Phone call -  Discouraged, vulnerable to interception.

Passwordless Single-Step Sign-In
Admins can optionally allow users to skip passwords at sign-in (1SV) when using a device passkey  (Android/IOS/Computer):

[Admin] Allow users to skip passwords at sign-in (beta)
[User] How do I sign in with a passkey instead of a password?


Workspace Support

As a Google Workspace admin, you have the added option to contact Workspace Support. The available support options will vary by subscription but can include live chat.

